# want some records to be displayed between a date range .Date is string value both input and the stored as well - in asp-net-mvc c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**I'm Using mvc5 .net4.5 Using c#**

It's About Entity Framework 
Disaster after Reaching to this point

i want some records to be displayed between a date range

For Example :`Table1.Where(both => both.OnDate <= from && both.OnDate >= from)`
Problem is
the date type stored in database  is : **dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt** (19-08-2014 10:10 AM) i.e onDate(string).
Input is in the format of **dd-MM-yyyy** (12-12-2012)i.e from(string) and to(string)

**want to retrieve all records between two date ranges**

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [EntityFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.aspx) (or [DbFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.aspx) with EF 6) in order to create a date from the `OnDate` string.

And create `DateTime` for the `from` and `to` strings in C# (`DateTime.Parse`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `datetime.date` property to compare against only the date portion and not time. Here is the link about [DateTime.Date](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx) for reference

What about..

```
Table1.Where(x => x.OnDate.Date >= fromDate && x.OnDate.Date <= toDate)
```

`both.OnDate.Date` gets only date-only portion of date

Comment: I've mentioned that OnDate is string not DateTime datatype